# Check a remote port is open and log with time stamp

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to check that a remote server port is open at a couple of times a day. I was hoping to use PowerShell and add it as a scheduled task.

I don’t know how to either have the time stamp recorded in the output or as part of the file name. I’ve been trying to use `Test-Netconnection` for this:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Port 7010 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Get-Date returns the current time and can be formatted as required

Comment: Thanks, but how would I incorporate that into my original code, please?  Could you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the date as the [calculated property](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/) like this:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName google.com -Port 443 | 
  Select *,@{label="Date";e={Get-Date}}
```

Make sure to choose only required properties instead of `*`.